# How to refresh or observe the Item is been added to cart using knockout JS UI component?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, knockoutjs, knockout

I have added a custom function which checks if the product has already been added in a quote or not. This works fine and shows button text accordingly. The only issue that it requires to refresh the page when adding to a quote button is pressed. How to observe these vars in Knockout Js so it updates on change.

```
return Component.extend({
    addedToCart: ko.observable(false),
    quote: {},
    /**
     * @override
     */
    initialize: function () {
        this._super();
        this.quote = customerData.get('quote');
        return this._super();
    },

    checkProductAddedToQuote: function (id) {

        var items = this.quote().items;
        if (!_.isUndefined(items)) {
            if ($.inArray(id, $.map(items, function (item) { return item.product_id; })) > -1) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false;
    },


});
```

in my phtml file I am accessing like this

```
<button data-bind="scope: 'quote'" type="button"
                    title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?>"
                    class="action primary toquote"
                    id="product-addtoquote-button">
        <span data-bind="text: quote().summary_count > 0 ? ( checkProductAddedToQuote('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getId() ?>') === true ? 'Added to Quote' : 'Add to Quote' ): 'Request a Quote'"></span>
    </button>
```

Comment: this may help - https://www.magemonkeys.com/magento-2-update-cart-using-ajax-when-quantity-change/

Comment: kamlesh, if you have to reflect immediately your ko function then you have to call a function on a click or any of the events that call your ko function immediate.

Comment: Right now your function is called on refresh the page, not on events like click. so, you have to change your logic of word change on click event.

Answer (score 0):

please use below code.

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (uiComponent, ko, customerData) {
    return uiComponent.extend({
        _config: '',
        _element: '',

        initialize: function (config, element) {
            this._super();
            this.cart = customerData.get('cart');
            this._config = config;
            this._element = element;
        },
        myConf: function () {
            return this._config;
        },
        getPrice: function () {
            var self = this;
            return ko.computed(function() {
                return self._config.min_price - self.cart().subtotalAmount;
            });
        },
        isEnable: function () {
            return this._config.is_enable;
        }
    });
});
```